# jquery TypeError: $(...).validate and TypeError: $(...).modal is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, validation

I have been working on a simple form submission. First, I wanted to create a modal alert before form submission. So, i used bootstrap's modal function, and repeatedly got

> TypeError: $(...).modal is not a function

After searching around the net for a lot of time, I added

```
jQuery.noConflict();
```

and code worked out. Then, I wanted to validate my form before invoking the modal. So, i am using the jQuery validation plugin to do the same. Then, I am getting this error:

> TypeError: $(...).validate is not a function*

Can someone kindly help me out as to what exactly is the problem I am facing. **All my jquery files seem to be in order.**

```
<head>
    <!jquery>
        <script src="../js/jquery.js"></script>     
    <!jquery form validation plugin>
        <script src="../js/formvalidator/lib/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="../js/formvalidator/dist/jquery.validate.js"></script>     
        <! Bootstraplinks>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../bootstrap/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">         
        <script src="../bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <!Alert Plugin links>
        <script src="../js/alert/lib/sweet-alert.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../js/alert/lib/sweet-alert.css">
</head>
<body>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery.noConflict();
        $("#addtype").validate();
        $("#button_submit").click(function(){
            if($("#addtype").valid()){
                $('#myModal').modal('show');
            }
        });
        $("#button_proceed").click(function(){
            $('#addtype').submit();
        });
    });
</body>
```

Comment: Further, If i put my bootstrap plugin after validation plugin, then try to run just the modal (without validation), i still get TypeError: $(...).modal is not a function.

Comment: don't use two versions of same file(jquery), first try to remove that

Comment: @PushkerYadav It is not same jquery file. It is a file the validation plugin uses. It is different from jquery file. The documentation of the plugin clearly states to add this file too (I have even opened and chcked it.. its different).

Comment: i believe it's `$('...').valid()` not `validate()`

Comment: I don't know if it makes a difference, but I never put `<script>` inside the head tags. `<link>` (ie CSS) goes in the head, and all the `<script>` goes right before the closing `</body>` tag. And make sure all bootstrap and jquery files are included in the proper order, then any code that uses their functions.

Answer (score 0):

You have two jquery files. Try removing one of them and see if it works.

You said it's not the same jquery file, but a number of jquery plugins will include the base jquery.js file (so that plug-ins will work "out of the box"). It says that the file is required because the plugin requires jquery to work. I've been doing some work with the DataTables plug-in, for example, and the jquery.js it includes in its js directory is definitely just the base jquery javascript file. If the file differs at first glance it might just be due to it being a different version of jquery or something. But I'm pretty sure that both files are doing the same thing. Just try removing one of them and see if it works.